# Collections.sort sorting 1 value improperly

Tags: java

I am implementing Collections.sort using a comparator in a simulation of a scheduling algorithm and for some reason it is mis-sorting 1 value.

The expected output of the sort should be (middle truncated):

```
PID=1, PEntry=1, PBurst=1
PID=2, PEntry=2, PBurst=1
.
.
.
PID=15, PEntry=15, PBurst=1
PID=16, PEntry=16, PBurst=1
PID=17, PEntry=17, PBurst=1
```

But it is giving me this (middle truncated):

```
PID=1, PEntry=1, PBurst=1
PID=2, PEntry=2, PBurst=1
.
.
.
PID=15, PEntry=15, PBurst=1
PID=17, PEntry=17, PBurst=1
PID=16, PEntry=16, PBurst=1
```

Comparator:

```
    private static Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> sortByComparator(Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> unsorted) {
            List<Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> linkedList = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>(unsorted.entrySet());
            Collections.sort(linkedList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>() {
                    public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> object1, Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> object2) {
                            return (object2.getValue().get(0)).compareTo(object2.getValue().get(0));
                    }
            });
            Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> sorted = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> it = linkedList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry = it.next();
                    sorted.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            return sorted;
    }
```

Comment: Sure, this is correct: `return (object2.getValue().get(0)).compareTo(object2.getValue().get(0));` ? This will always be `true`.

Comment: Omg... I feel so stupid right now. That late night coding is messing with my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `object2.getValue().get(0)` with itself. that should be :

```
 return (object1.getValue().get(0)).compareTo(object2.getValue().get(0));
```